# Slow SQL query return - How to get better results?

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I’ve been asked to write a query that returns accounts with only specific action codes (internal name). There are 6 codes that have to be on the account and no other codes can be on. The table is stored in a table called tblTrans (see below) :

```
AccountNo   ActionCode  TransactionNo
1234        Code1       45646453
1234        Code2       88758475
1234        Code3       48978978
1234        Code4       15687898
1234        Code5       59878988
1234        Code6       12345677
2548        Code1       45464533
2548        Code2       89789489
2548        Code3       89789781
2548        Code4       16878983
2548        Code5       59889884
2548        Code6       12456776
2548        Code12      12348887
```

So the desired output would only return account 1234.

Currently this is being done with a query like

```
SELECT AccountNo, ActionCode, TransactionNo     
FROM tblTrans AS t1 
INNER JOIN
        tblTrans AS t2 ON t1.AccountNo = t2.AccountNo
        tblTrans AS t3 ON t2.AccountNo = t3.AccountNo
        tblTrans AS t4 ON t3.AccountNo = t4.AccountNo
        tblTrans AS t5 ON t4.AccountNo = t5.AccountNo
        tblTrans AS t6 ON t5.AccountNo = t6.AccountNo
WHERE t1.ActionCode = 'Code1' 
  AND t2.ActionCode = 'Code2'
  AND t3.ActionCode = 'Code3'
  AND t4.ActionCode = 'Code4'
  AND t5.ActionCode = 'Code5'
  AND t5.ActionCode = 'Code6'
  AND t6.AccountNo NOT IN (SELECT ActionCode 
                           FROM tblTrans 
                           WHERE ActionCode IN ('Code12'))
```

Sorry if the syntax is out I have had to change a few details for security reasons!

This actually runs very slowly and chokes the system up little. My question is, is there a better way to write this type of query. I don’t know much about CTE’s but sounds like it would fit?

Answer (score 1):

This should return AccountNo's where there is ONLY your desired codes.

```
SELECT AccountNo
FROM   tblTrans
GROUP BY AccountNo
HAVING  Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code1' Then 1 End) > 0
        And Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code2' Then 1 End) > 0
        And Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code3' Then 1 End) > 0
        And Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code4' Then 1 End) > 0
        And Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code5' Then 1 End) > 0
        And Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code6' Then 1 End) > 0
        And Sum(Case When ActionCode IN ('Code1', 'Code2', 'Code3', 'Code4', 'Code5', 'Code6') Then 0 Else 1 End) = 0
```

I modified the query.  This one should perform better.  If the performance is still not acceptable, then you should probably consider adding an index to your table.

To return all the data...

```
; With FilteredData As
(
    SELECT AccountNo
    FROM   tblTrans
    GROUP BY AccountNo
    HAVING  Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code1' Then 1 End) > 0
            And Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code2' Then 1 End) > 0
            And Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code3' Then 1 End) > 0
            And Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code4' Then 1 End) > 0
            And Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code5' Then 1 End) > 0
            And Sum(Case When ActionCode = 'Code6' Then 1 End) > 0
            And Sum(Case When ActionCode IN ('Code1', 'Code2', 'Code3', 'Code4', 'Code5', 'Code6') Then 0 Else 1 End) = 0
)
Select  TblTrans.AccountNo, ActionCode, TransactionNumber
From    TblTrans
        Inner Join FilteredData
            On tblTrans.AccountNo = FilteredData.AccountNo
```

Comment: Why do think, that this will perform better?

Comment: This version performs better than my first attempt.  I say this based on comparing the execution plans.

Comment: Was the problem in `DISTINCT`?